# what is the difference between two similar javascript selectors

Tags: javascript, selector

What is the difference of this two selectors:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll("#srow .cell");
  console.log(x[1]);
}
myFunction();
```

and

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("srow").querySelectorAll(".cell");
  console.log(x[1]);
}
myFunction();
```

both return the second element

Comment: `.srow` is a class selector.... `document.getElementById` will select only those elements having specified ID..

Comment: @ edited, in both cases is an id

Comment: IMO, Both are same.. I mean will return same set of collection...

Comment: They're functionally identical. The first is *probably* faster but I'd have to do some testing to be sure.

Comment: @Rayon Slight difference where the first case will not throw an error if `#srow` does not exist.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yeah, too deep :) I'm trying to test something ..

Comment: @mcmwhfy Actually there are more differences. If for some reason there are multiple elements with the same id `#srow`, the second case will only return a partial list of all `#srow .cell`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I'm trying to get all parents and their childrens  from a container list.

Comment: @mcmwhfy Take a look at [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/1m3k3gzL/). Those two cases are functionally different.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yes but should not exist two identic id's in html.

Comment: @mcmwhfy If the developer follows the rules set in the HTML spec then in the case of there exists at least one of such element, they should both return the same nodeList. However if there exists multiple elements with the same `id`, since this is an unexpected behavior there is no guarantee in how `.querySelectorAll` should behave, which you might get different results from the first case but consistent results from the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are similar but perform different things.

- The first case returns all elements with class `.cell` which has at least one parent that has an id `srow`.
- The second case gets *one* of all elements with id `srow` then returns all child elements with class `.cell`.

Here is an example that demonstrate their differences: https://jsfiddle.net/1m3k3gzL/

Although HTML5 explicitly prohibits repeated `id`s, typical browsers usually allow this kind of things to happen.

Comment: so is not a stupid question after all ;)  Anyway I saw these differences on my code and I tried to find more info about this scenario .